# Lie derivative $L_X$ formula applied to vector field $Y$

Tags: differential-geometry

I get confused with notation in Differential Geometry, therefore I am asking for your help.

Given a manifold $\mathcal{M}$, we define the Lie derivative operator $L_a$ of a form $\omega$ respective to vector field $a$ by Cartan's (magic) formula $d(\iota_a \omega) + \iota_a d \omega$, whose notation corresponds differential operator $d$ and interior product $\iota$. Terms $d(\iota_a \omega)$ and $\iota_a d \omega$ correspond to expressions $a^i \partial_i \alpha_j dx^j$ and $[(\partial_j a^i) \alpha_i + a^i (\partial_i \alpha_j) ] dx^j$ respectively, according to my calculations, which result on expression $[(\partial_j a^i) \alpha_i + a^i (\partial_i \alpha_j) ] dx^j$ for Lie derivative $L_a \omega$. This may be wrong, of course.

Originally, my supervisor and I wanted to calculate the Lie transport $L_a \nabla = 0$, or equivalently, $L_a \omega = 0$. My toy example is to find the 1-form $\alpha$ which is Lie-transported  along vector field $(x^4, x^5, x^1 x^5 - x^2 x^4, 0, 0)$, the Roger Brockett integrator. The required partial derivatives $\partial_j a^i$.

\begin{align*}
    \partial_k a^4 &= \partial_k a^5 = 0 \\
    \partial_4 a^1 &= 1, \, \partial_k a^1 = 0 \mbox{ otherwise} \\ 
    \partial_5 a^2 &= 1, \, \partial_k a^2 = 0 \mbox{ otherwise} \\
    \partial_1 a^3 &= x^5, \, \partial_2 a^3 = -x^4, \partial_3 a^3 = 0, \partial_4 a^3 = -x^2, \partial_5 a^3 = x^1
\end{align*}

I even built this system below, but I do not know if it is possible to calculate a closed formula for 1-norm $\omega$.

\begin{equation}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 0 & x^5 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & -x^4 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & -x^2 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & x^1 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
        \alpha_1 \\
        \alpha_2 \\
        \alpha_3 \\
        \alpha_4 \\
        \alpha_5 \\
    \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}
        \partial_1 \alpha_1 & \partial_2 \alpha_1 & \partial_3 \alpha_1 & \partial_4 \alpha_1 & \partial_n \alpha_1 \\
        \partial_1 \alpha_2 & \partial_2 \alpha_2 & \partial_3 \alpha_2 & \partial_4 \alpha_2 & \partial_n \alpha_1 \\
        \partial_1 \alpha_3 & \partial_2 \alpha_3 & \partial_3 \alpha_3 & \partial_4 \alpha_3 & \partial_n \alpha_n \\
        \partial_1 \alpha_4 & \partial_2 \alpha_4 & \partial_3 \alpha_4 & \partial_4 \alpha_4 & \partial_n \alpha_n \\
        \partial_1 \alpha_5 & \partial_2 \alpha_5 & \partial_3 \alpha_5 & \partial_4 \alpha_5 & \partial_n \alpha_n \\
    \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
        x^4 \\
        x^5 \\
        x^1 x^5 - x^2 x^4 \\
        0 \\
        0
    \end{bmatrix} = 0
\end{equation}

My question is to have some feedback on calculation development and ask for help to find some close formula for 1-form $\omega$.

Thank you!

Comment: The metric term which you find weird not having is in the connection $\nabla$ via the Christoffel symbols: $\nabla_kX^i=\partial_kX^i+\Gamma^i_{\ell k}X^\ell\,.$ Rather than asking ChatGPT I encourage you to derive the following expressions: $$L_XY=[X,Y]=(X^i\partial_iY^k)\partial_k-(Y^i\partial_iX^k)\partial_k=(X^i\nabla_iY^k)\partial_k-(Y^i\nabla_iX^k)\partial_k\,.$$  Question: what symmetry in the Christoffel symbols allows to deduce the last equality? And what property of $g$ guarantees that symmetry? BTW: The expression $[X,Y]^k\nabla_k$ by ChatGPT looks wrong to me.

Comment: Great, thanks Kurt. May I ask you about how to solve a killing condition? I will edit the question.

Comment: Before I calculate what your supervisor wants you to do I think we should fix a few more basics. You write that "terms $d(\iota_a \omega)$ and $\iota_a d \omega$ correspond to expressions $a^i \partial_i \alpha_j dx^j$ and $[(\partial_j a^i) \alpha_i + a^i (\partial_i \alpha_j) ] dx^j$ respectively". How can their sum then be $[(\partial_j a^i) \alpha_i + a^i (\partial_i \alpha_j) ] dx^j\,?$ (That last expression looks like the correct Lie derivative btw.)

Comment: Thanks for typo fix. I multiplied the term by 2 on matricial representation as well. I am sometimes boggled by what I cannot do and get stuck. I come here, I say out loud, as described at SO policies. This is what SO is for,  I think.

Comment: Totally wrong. I wrote that $L_a\omega=[(\partial_j a^i) \alpha_i + a^i (\partial_i \alpha_j) ] dx^j$ is correct. Apparently that was a coincidence. What is incorrect are your expressions for $d(\iota_a\omega)$ and $\iota_a(d\omega)\,.$ Each of those two contains *two* terms. When you add them something cancels and gives the two terms for $L_a\omega\,.$

Comment: May you point a book with explicit expressions for Cartan's formula? Thanks! :)

Comment: See answer. Do you know how $\iota_a$ works?

Comment: Thanks, your contribution is valuable to this community. I am an engineer by formation, some professors are sloopy on their statements, I need some help, like yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the notation
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{a}&=a^i\partial_i\,,&\boldsymbol{\omega}&=b_j\,dx^j
\end{align}
for better readablity.
By Cartan's formula
\begin{align}
L_\boldsymbol{a}\boldsymbol{\omega}&=d(\iota_\boldsymbol{a}\boldsymbol{\omega})+\iota_\boldsymbol{a}(d\boldsymbol{\omega})\,,\\
\end{align}
we have to calculate
\begin{align}
d\boldsymbol{\omega}&=\partial_ib_j\,dx^i\wedge dx^j\,,&\iota_\boldsymbol{a}(d\boldsymbol{\omega})&=a^i\partial_ib_j\,dx^j-\underbrace{a^j\partial_ib_j\,dx^i}\,,\\[2mm]
\iota_{\boldsymbol{a}}\boldsymbol{\omega}&=a^jb_j\,,&
d(\iota_{\boldsymbol{a}}\boldsymbol{\omega})&=\underbrace{a^j\partial_ib_j\,dx^i}+b_j\partial_ia^j\,dx^i\,.
\end{align}
Since the two underbraced terms cancel we get
$$
\boxed{\quad\phantom{\Big|}L_\boldsymbol{a}\boldsymbol{\omega}=
a^j\partial_jb_i\,dx^i+b_j\partial_ia^j\,dx^i\,.\quad}
$$
In your notation $\boldsymbol{\omega}=\alpha_j\,dx^j$ this is
$$
L_a\boldsymbol{\omega}=\Big[(\partial_j a^i) \alpha_i + a^i (\partial_i \alpha_j) \Big]\,dx^j\,.
$$

Your vector field is now given by
$$
a^i=\begin{pmatrix}x^4\\ x^5\\ x^1 x^5 - x^2 x^4\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
The simplest $1$-form $\boldsymbol{\omega}=b_j\,dx^j$ whose Lie derivative $L_\boldsymbol{a}\boldsymbol{\omega}$ is zero is one that annihilates
$\boldsymbol{a}\,:$
$$
a^jb_j\equiv 0
$$
and is closed: $d\boldsymbol{\omega}=0\,.$ There are obviously many choices. For example
$$
\boldsymbol{\omega}=dx^4+dx^5\,.
$$
Slightly less trivial examples could be obtained by making the ansatz
$$
\begin{pmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\b_3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a^1\\a^2\\a^3\end{pmatrix}\times \begin{pmatrix}c^1\\c^2\\c^3\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
In fact, all $1$-forms that annihilate  $\boldsymbol{a}$ have first three components $b_1,b_2,b_3$ that are of this form plus arbitrary components $b_4,b_5\,.$ Among those forms I would now seek those that are closed.
For simplicity I would set $b_4=b_5=0\,.$
This leads to first order PDEs for $c_1,c_2,c_3\,.$
Fewer unknow functions, higher change to find examples.

At the moment I do not know a systematic approach to this problem. Not to mention the more general problem of solving $L_\boldsymbol{a}\boldsymbol{\omega}=0$ for $\boldsymbol{\omega}\,.$

Comment: Thanks, Kurt. I understand that for the closed form $d\omega=0$ AND the inclusion  $\iota_a\omega=0$, the annihilator as you mention, the resulting form is indeed a solution. Can you see some systematic way to obtain a minimum set of linearly independent 1-forms? Thanks!

Comment: I see the following: without solving the resulting partial differential equation, we can establish equality conditions: $\iota_a(\omega) = 0$, $d\omega = 0$, $d(\iota_a\omega) = 0$, $\iota_a d\omega = 0$, each which alone is not sufficient, but necessary in certain condition composition. However, the correct arrangement makes it necessary and sufficient.

Comment: would you clarify the operator $\times$ and subsequent paragraph? Thank you!

Comment: $\times$ is the cross product in $\mathbb R^3\,.$ As we know: it makes $b$ orthogonal to $a\,.$

Comment: I am not sure, if there is an equivalent to cross-product due interchangeability between brackets and cross produc sometimes. I understand, we deal with 3-dimensional vectors and the intuition says there will be some not-null vector $c$ such that inner product $c^i a_i = 0$ which is given by $b \times a$, for another perpendicular vector $b$ to $a$. I think, this is what you mean, right!?

Comment: Anyhow, in this case, the inclusion $\iota_a \omega$ of a 1-form with vector $a$ is a map, am I correct? What does mean, a map differential being zero?

Comment: I was under the impression that we agreed previously that annihilating $\boldsymbol{a}$ is equivalent to $a^ib_j\equiv0\,.$ Does that ring a bell? (Hint: it is formally the same as the vanishing of the scalar product in $\mathbb R^5\,.$)

Comment: You are correct. My concern refers to cross-product in higher dimensions, which may not suit the same way, although useful to this particular example for given condition $b^4=b^5=0$.

Comment: I am aware of the problems with cross products in other than three dimensions. Since $a^4=a^5=0$ we can choose for $b_4,b_5$ whatever we want and still have $a^ib_j\equiv0\,.$ Good luck solving this case further.

Comment: Thanks! I will leave a last remark for you to think about, feel free to ignore:

We may improve the answer by covering other scenarios from additional conditions: 1. $\iota_a \alpha = 0$ and $\iota_a d\alpha = 0$: annihilation of both form and its differential; 2. $d(\iota_a \alpha) = 0$ and $d\alpha = 0$: closed inclusion map and form; 3. $d(\iota_a \alpha) = 0$ and $\iota_a d\alpha = 0$: closed inclusion and annihilation form.